# MVC OutputCaching - why should not use page directive?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

Reading [Output Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs) of MVC.

As per the site, `Don't use the page <%@ OutputCache %> directive in an MVC view. This directive is bleeding over from the Web Forms world and should not be used in an ASP.NET MVC application.` I can understand we have used OutputCache in ASP.NET. But why the same should not be used in MVC as page directive? Is there any specific reason of why should not be used?

I am new to MVC. So, please let me know if I missed something here. Thanks!

Comment: `Is there any specific reason of why should not be used?` Because it is clearly documented as the 'wrong way'. You should put it on the action (or controller), not the view. That is the "MVC way" (as clearly discussed in the page you linked to). Is there a particular reason you don't want to do it the standard way?

Comment: @mjwills, thanks for the comment. I am new and not aware that it's  a standard way to declare in controller. Could have been better if mentioned in the site. But, thanks for highlighting.

Comment: `Could have been better if mentioned in the site.` The page states right near the top - `Enabling Output Caching
You enable output caching by adding an [OutputCache] attribute to either an individual controller action or an entire controller class.`

Comment: @bommelding I thought Microsoft would take care of updating article.